Prevent iOS app from using insecure ciphers
I’m trying to prevent my React Native app from using insecure ciphers. To test this, I’m making a request to https://tls-v1-2.badssl.com using Axios. However, I want to enforce the use of TLS 1.3 in my app, so I expect the request to fail because the server only supports TLS 1.2.
Here is my fetch code using Axios:
import axios from 'axios';

const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('https://tls-v1-2.badssl.com');
    console.log('Request successful:', response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Request failed:', error);
  }
};

Info.plist
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>tls-v1-2.badssl.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.3</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>

the request still succeeds when I expected it to fail, as the server only supports TLS 1.2.
Is this the correct whey to block insecure ciphers? I do not have access to ther server

I wrote a small Swift app to connect to that server. Without any settings in info.plist, connection was successful.  After adding your info.plist settings, connection failed.  Maybe Axios does not use iOS's in-built URLRequest and so ATS settings do not apply?  You will need to investigate how to apply restrictions to Axios.

Note that tls1.2 is not itself insecure. A server can use tls 1.2 but remove the insecure cipher suites
